# Using Visual Studio 2015 for existing node-js client-side web projects

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, package.json

I have a team working on a client-side node.js application. The sources are stored in a source control. I'd like to modify and debug this application in Visual Studio 2015. They use other IDEs, and I would not like to add additional VS-specific files such as .sln to source control.

I'm able to clone the repository, create a separate empty solution and add the repository as an "Existing Web Site". However, Visual Studio do not recognize package.json, and do not install dependencies as it would for MVC6 projects. Consequently gruntfile.js would not work either.

Is there any way to make Visual Studio see and process package.json, or I'm on a wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Existing Web Site" option, create a new solution and add items to it. Web Site Projects types are a different, legacy project type.

Comment: What project time would you recommend?

Comment: If you have install the node.js tools, you should use the Blank nodeJS Project template.